# Test Exception Raise in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, assert

I have written a simple non-negative number Fibonacci function in OCaml, where I raise an exception if a negative number is passed in.

```
let rec fib (n:int) : int =
  match n with
  | a when a < 0 -> invalid arg ("Positive numbers only")
  | i when i < 2 -> n
  | _ -> fib (n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

  let _ = assert (fib(-1))
```

The function is very rudimentary (it's my first OCaml program), but my question involves testing that an exception is raised when I execute `fib(-1)`.

```
let _ = assert (? = fib(-1))
```

How do I assert for this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of @SteveVinoski is excellent, but apparently this is a homework problem and not a genuine question :-)

The `try` ... `with` statement is the piece of OCaml that handles exceptions. That's what you'll need to use to verify whether an exception is raised. You can use it to write your own version of `assert_raises`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [`OUnit2`](http://ounit.forge.ocamlcore.org/api-ounit-dev/OUnit2.html) for testing. It provides an `assert_raises` function that's perfect for this case:

```
open OUnit2

let fib_test () =
  let f = fun () -> fib(-1) in
  OUnit2.assert_raises (Invalid_argument "Positive numbers only") f
```

The `invalid_arg` function raises an `Invalid_argument` exception.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this without using a library. I've already explored using `assert_raises` and it does exactly what I want, but in my assignment I'm not allowed to use libraries.